# Accessing C# variable in javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I'm going to design a website for DMS (educational domain) in C#.NET, which I am new to.

In one of my ASPX pages, I want to disable a menu, which is in JavaScript, according to `accessright`.

The `accessright` stored in database table `login` as one attribute in SQL server, and I want to retrieve that `accessright` to one C# variable and want to access that variable in JavaScript.

If there is another possible approach please tell.

Comment: I would note that hiding something based on a users access rights shouldn't be done in JavaScript (unless its a really non-sensitive thing). If I really shouldn't see it, I can just open my Developer Tools console and try `iCanHazAccess = true;` and up pops your menu. If you're catering this server-side too, then thats fine

Answer (score 10):

Well there is one shortcut we used to use during the ASP days, this still works in ASP.NET
In the page codebehind declare a public  property say `public int MyInteger`
In the aspx put this

```
<script>
    function GetMyValue()
    {
     var someVar = <%=this.MyInteger%>;
     //Do something
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i like this more than the solution by Scarlet Garden. Why? With your solution you don't need to rebuild if you want to change something!

Answer (score 2):

I found this during my problem with passing server silde variable to a Javascript variable. The best way to do this is using `eval()` javascript method:

```
function GetMyValue(){      
    eval("var someVar = " + parseInt<%=this.MyInteger%>"));
    //Do something     
}
```

Use it and enjoy it. 
;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code I quickly googled. http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/7/63763/using-c-variable-in-java.aspx It should point you in the right direction. strvariable is your C# variable.

```
    <INPUT id="hd" style="Z-INDEX: 101; LEFT: 16px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 144px" type="hidden"  value="<%=strvariable %>">

<script language="javascript">
function Button_Click()
{
    alert(document.getElementById('hd').value); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not access server side variables in client-side code. Only way is to use an AJAX library or to inject your variables to page as client side script.

Inject your variable's value to page like that :

```
string script = string.Format("var myVariable = '{0}';", vaiable.ToString());
if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("myScript"))
{
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(_Default), "myScript", script, true);
}
```

and in your javascript functions use **myVariable** as your server side variable.

But I thing you should start with [Client Side or Server Side](http://websiteowner.info/articles/cgi/whichside.asp) concept.

Comment: that is simply not true! ever thought of <%= this.VAR %> ??

Comment: Why not true ? I use it everyday, and nothing wrong with this. 
<%= this.VAR %> way is some kind of spaghetty code. I don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

In our code base we implemented a technology called [RemoteInvoke](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/support/archive/2008/11/21/remoteinvokes-invoke-remotely.aspx), whereby javascript can call methods on the server without a postback.  Effectively, it is call-by-name with dynamic binding on the server side.

The name of the method and its javascript arguments get bundled up and passed to the server, the server unrolls them and finds the best matching method to call.  The rules are that you can only call methods with the RemoteInvokable attribute and the allowable data types are numbers, strings and booleans.  The code that handles the call delegation will match on signature doing approximate matching where possible (ie, if you pass a floating point number as an arg, it will favor a method with that name and signature, but if there is none, it will find one with a matching integral argument.

Accessing a server side variable can be implemented through RemoteInvoke.

Comment: This looks promising, but is probably more than the poster needs or cares to implement.  :\