# Pass C# variable to html

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use jQuery to call a variable from C#. I can't seem to access the variable sqlReq. My end goal would to be able to add my own SQL information to this PieChart. But I don't really know how to call and set C# SQL requests in HTML, or jQuery...

I've looked at many examples, but I can't seem to get a specific answer. I'm not sure if it has to do with not having a reference to the C# class, or what.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace KendoUIApp3.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public String sqlReq = "";
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("someDB");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
            SqlDataReader read;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM P";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlConn.Open();

            read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            sqlReq = read.ToString();
            sqlConn.Close();
            Console.Write(read);
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\Users\215000712\source\repos\KendoUIApp3\KendoUIApp3\Scripts\kendo\sqlQuery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">
        <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
            <div id="chart" style="background: center no-repeat url('../content/shared/styles/world-map.png');"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function createChart() {
                $("#chart").kendoChart({
                    title: {
                        position: "bottom",
                        text: "Share of Internet Population Growth, 2007 - 2012"

                    },
                    legend: {
                        visible: false
                    },
                    chartArea: {
                        background: ""
                    },
                    seriesDefaults: {
                        labels: {
                            visible: true,
                            background: "transparent",
                            template: "#= category #: \n #= value#%"
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        type: "pie",
                        startAngle: 150,
                        data: [{
                            category: "Asia",
                            value: 53.8,
                            color: "#9de219"
                        }, {
                            category: "Europe",
                            value: 16.1,
                            color: "#90cc38"
                        }, {
                            category: "Latin America",
                            value: 11.3,
                            color: "#068c35"
                        }, {
                            category: "Africa",
                            value: 9.6,
                            color: "#006634"
                        }, {
                            category: "Middle East",
                            value: 5.2,
                            color: "#004d38"
                        }, {
                            category: "North America",
                            value: 3.6,
                            color: "#033939"
                        }]
                    }],
                    tooltip: {
                        visible: true,
                        format: "{0}%"
                    }
                });
            }

            $(document).ready(createChart);
            $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
        </script>

    <div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br />
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                alert("@sqlReq")
            })
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An easy solution is to put your sqlReq value, inside the viewbag and access it from there(like you do with the title). But it depends on what you wanna do you the data. Is it a onetime on load thing?

Comment: You don't call C# from JavaScript, and you don't call JavaScript from C#. Did you do any research into how ASP.NET MVC applications should be put together? It's a web framework, so at the end of the day you're limited to sending HTML, JavaScript, and CSS to the browser over the HTTP protocol. You don't directly call C# from JavaScript. In MVC, you typically query for your data in a data layer, which is called from your controller. The controller passes the resulting information into the view as a Model, and then the View determines what HTML gets sent to the client.

Comment: @mason true however you CAN access C# variables in javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665995/accessing-c-sharp-variable-in-javascript

Comment: You're not handling your [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) objects (SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader) correctly.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet That's embedding the value of a C# value into the HTML document that's generated in the View and sent to the client. You're not accessing it "from JavaScript". The distinction is important, because many people new to web development struggle to understand client side vs server side code and how they interact. Stating that you can "access variables" like that is just misleading.

Comment: @mason Well.. you can? I don't see how it's misleading, but to each their own.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet No, you can't. Think about my last comment. You are embedding the value of C# variable into an HTML document that's sent to the client. The JavaScript isn't running on the server. It's not "accessing" a C# variable. The distinction is important and it's not just semantics, and you continuing to state that you can is just going to confuse someone new to web development.

Comment: @mason I never said you were wrong, however for someone who's new to web development doesn't need to be an expert on the level of specific that you're talking about. You're not wrong, but really what does it add to explain that "it's embedding" and not "accessing via javascript" I think the point is you can do it if you want. I'll stop after this since this is becoming a discussion but to people who are just learning it really doesn't make a difference. (and it's used in production too).

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet This doesn't require you to be an expert to understand. It's the very foundations of how web applications are put together. And you don't want to be starting out with a bad foundation. You can't directly access C# variables from JavaScript running in the browser on a client. Period. If you continue to tell people you can, then you're doing them a disservice.

Comment: "bad foundation" for using something that ASP.NET offers? :thinking:. To each their own.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet This isn't about what ASP.NET does and doesn't offer. It's about how you explain what ASP.NET (and web development in general) work. If you explain something wrong that's so fundamental to web development, that's giving them a bad foundation to build their knowledge on, and it can be very detrimental to their future learning and implementation. Let's teach them the right way from the beginning to avoid those issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller passes values to HTML, you need to post back if you want data to move from your page to your C# controller (e.g. using Ajax).

The good news is, there's a pretty easy way of sending values to your HTML.  For example, in your controller, create a list of strings, and add them to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new List<string> {"A", "B"});
    }
```

Then, in your view, refer to this model at the top of the page:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
```

You can now get those references and display them in a table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
@foreach (var entry in Model)
{
    <tr><td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelName => entry)</td></tr>
}
```

The model I've used for this example is just a list of strings, but your model could be ANY model you've made in C#.

In your example, this would likely be the results of your SQL read - hard to say without knowing what your data looks like, but you can probably use `@model string` in your view, and this in your controller:

```
return View(sqlReq.ToString())
```

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand View... but in the most basic way. I just want view a String "sqlReq" in html code.

Comment: @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    @model string = sqlReq;
} Like So?

Comment: You've sent the data to the page, now you need to display it.  E.g. @Html.DisplayForModel()

Comment: Usually you separate them, like this: @model HelpPageApiModel

@{
    var description = Model.ApiDescription;
    ViewBag.Title = description.HttpMethod.Method + " " + description.RelativePath;
}

Comment: You've passed sqlReq to your view?  You've added @model string to the top of your view, and you've added @Html.DisplayForModel() somewhere in the body of your HTML?  This should now work.  If not, try passing a dummy test string to your view and/or debugging whats happening when you open this page...

Comment: If not, try reading this - http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/mvc-view

Comment: Hey I got it to work.. is this the best method for variables?

Comment: Yes, this is the best method - as you can pass a C# model or collection, you can basically pass whatever you need.  Viewbag gets limited pretty fast.